# Is there a way to download Atmel examples?

Tags: c, avr, atmel

I'm getting start with a new Atmel board , for that I found this documentation :

http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/xmega.drivers.usart.example.xmega_a3bu_xplained/html/index.html
my question is is there a way to download this project or sourc ? 
thanks

Comment: Why not email them & ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via the download link at the side of the page you linked to ( http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/download.html ) and clicking on the "Download" link for the ASF source code (not the tools).

Comment: thanks for your answer. do you mean the zip file here :http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRSOFTWAREFRAMEWORK.aspx?tab=overview  

?